# Nivo Slider for wordpress not loading images - server responds with 404 error

Tags: wordpress, slider, http-status-code-404, nivo-slider

I have the Nivo slider for wordpress install on a website I am working on. The plugin worked great until recently when it suddenly stopped working after I had made a series of seemly unrelated changes to the custom theme.

The slider shows the following error in console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://50.116.65.195/~cooperfd/wp-content/uploads/nivoslider4wp_files/17_s.png
```

I am unable to see this file via my web browser, however, if I navigate to this location in my FTP client the file is there. All permissions for the file and folders are set to 777.

If it makes any difference I am also unable to see the file from backend of the plugin.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: What are these "unrelated changes"?

Comment: Same issue. 
The images which came  with the  theme work fine but when I replace them with other images, it  stops loading them.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same thing and in my case, the culprit was the server which ran on Linux.
The names of the images were in capital letters whereas, on the page, they were in small letters.
My local Windows machine didn't show any problem in accessing those pictures, but as soon as they were uploaded on the server, they were inaccessible.
So, please check the spelling/case of the names of the images.